# dockerでbuildエラーが出力されてしまう

Tags: docker

MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020)
OS：macOS BigSur(バージョン11.4)
docker (Version:20.10.7)

Dockerを利用してUbuntuベースのPython開発環境を作ろうとしましたが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
=> ERROR [internal] load build definition from Python                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 40B                                        0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Python:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open .Trash: operation not permitted
(base) imaimasayuki@imaimasayukinoMacBook-Air ~ % docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

dockerfileの内容は、以下の通りです。

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo wget vim curl gawk make gcc

RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sh Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh -b  && \
    rm -f Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -  && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV PATH $PATH:/root/anaconda3/bin

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pandas_datareader
RUN pip install mplfinance

RUN wget --quiet http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz -O ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
    cd ta-lib/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
    make && \
    sudo make install && \
    cd .. && \
    pip install TA-Lib && \
    rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /workspace

CMD ["jupyter-lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0","--port=8888" ,"--no-browser", "--allow-root", "--LabApp.token=''"]
```

それから、以下のコマンドでbuildをしました。

```
docker build -t jlab:latest -f Python /PATH/
```

何が原因で起きている事象なのか分からなくかなり時間を使っています。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

macのterminalで実行しているのであれば、権限が不足している可能性が高いです。
以下リンクにもある通り、システム環境設定 -> セキュリティ -> フルディスクアクセスにterminalを追加してください。
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376916/cannot-ls-trash-in-the-terminal-in-catalina-operation-not-permitted

セキュリティ的な懸念がある場合、terminalがアクセスできる場所へdockerfileを置き、そちらでbuildしてください。
例えばデスクトップなどです。 https://teratail.com/questions/327273

追記
デスクトップへ移動させたら以下コマンドを実行してください。

```
cd ~/Desktop
docker build -t jlab:latest .
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記の内容を試みましたが、改善しないです。
フルディスクアクセスにterminalを追加した事とデスクトップにディレクトリーを作成して行ってみました。

Comment: 以下のメッセージが出力されます。





failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount124536371/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: 失礼しました。カレントをDockerfileのpathに切り替えた上で     docker build -t jlab:latest . コマンドでbuildを実行してください。


ファイルパスを明示的に指定したい場合は、-fに適切なpathを指定してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り、カレントをdockerfileのpathに切り替えたら実行できました。